# Windows 7 host VirtualBox full-screen crash

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, crash, fullscreen

I have installed VirtualBox on my main drive. When I run (host: Windows 7, updated) my virtual machine works fine until I try to enable full-screen*. Then it crashes with the following error:

*The instruction at 0x00000000 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be written. 
Click OK to terminate the program.*

Some info:

- 64-bit windows 7
- Intel i7 3630QM with integrated Intel HD 4000
- Nvidia GTX680M, fully updated drivers
- AVG free antivirus

I've tried:

- setting the shortcut to launch in directx9
- disabling my gtx680m
- running as administrator
- edit: trying a different virtual machine
- edit: disabling my anti-virus

I would love to be able to run any of my virtual machines in fullscreen. Why is this happening?

*My problem is **NOT** that I can't get the right resolution.

Comment: Have you tried this with other VM's?  Try a version of Linux and see if you get the same error.  It seems like it's a problem with a certain call.

Comment: I just tried a version with ubuntu, the same thing happened. I think the problem is in my windows..

Comment: VirtualBox is notoriously picky about graphics cards and drivers.  Check their website to see if they list a known-good driver version for your card.  You may have to revert back to an old version of your nVidia driver.

Comment: I have the exact same effect. Win7 64bit host and as soon as the VM goes fullscreen it crashes with exactly the message you showed. Your situation is not unique.

Comment: I'm getting this same error on two Win 7 hosts running several Linux distros. I'm using VBox version `4.3.20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this by simply uninstalling VirtualBox 4.3.16, reboot and then install VirtualBox 4.3.12.
I downloaded the older version from here: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.12/

Answer (score 6):

Could also try unticking "Mini Toolbar" in Settings -> General -> Advanced

That stopped the crash on "Full screen" for me - but I still have the other size problem.

I found the answer here:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=65274

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "fix" this issue with starting VM´s of Virtual Box (`4.3.20`) only if Virtual Box itself is in fullscreenmode. VM´s are working then without problems in fullscreen mode too. Anyways - changing the VM-window to another size results in a crash again.